# event.target inside table body gives wrong context, with an overlapping div of custom context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Update**

below question is what I asked earlier. I have found that it is menu div that causes problem. On click event on `td` I open a custom context menu. Div of menu overlaps a little bit of td. After that everything like context menu and all other `tds` works fine. But overlapped td can not find correct context so it shows top most div.

My question is how can I find td that is a little overlapped? I tried to see with suppressing pointer event on context menu. In that case td work but context menu closes instantly.

> If I click in a td with context menu and then drag my mouse without
>   leaving then I get correct results!!!

[image]

**Previous Question**
I have a page with elements like input, button and a DataTable table. I want to know
If `td` is `clicked` then 'open a menu' which works.

Now if user 'click anywhere on page except this' then 'close menu'

To open a menu I do this (works):

```
$(document).on('click', '#tbl tbody tr td', function () {
   //open menu
});
```

To close condition is if user (click anywhere except `#tbl tbody tr td`)
So I do this:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
   console.log(e.target);
});
```

This thing works anywhere on page and gives correct target. even on `thead`
and `tfoot` but not inside `tbody`. It gives top most `div` if I click
on `td` iniside tbody.

I am using DataTable and table is drawn dynamically. Though `thead and tfoot` are drawn same way but I can find if user clicked in `th` but not `td`. I am using jQuery 2.1.1

html page is similar to this:

```
<div>
    <input id="txtInput" type="text" class="form-control dt CLICKsHOWScORRECTtARGET"/>
    <button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="0">Search</button>
</div>
<div id="topMostReturnedForTDonly">
    <div id="fewLevelsOfDivNotReturned">
         <table id="tbl">
             <tr><td tag="clickOpensMenu">TEXT</td>
                <td tag="butClickCanNotCloseAsTargetShowsTopMost">TEXT</td></tr>
         </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SOURCE OF BUG**
Here is the code which is causing issue:

I have menu html:

```
<div id="menu" class="cmenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#" class="billSummary">Bill Summary</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="shareSummary">Share Summary</a></li>
       <li style="color: lightgray" class="closeContextMenu">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CLOSE - X</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I comment this code then correct target is shown.
here is how I am using this div:

```
var rgtClickContextMenu = document.getElementById('menu');
$(document).on('mousedown', '#tblJ1 tbody tr td', function (e) {
   if (e.which == 3) {
       rgtClickContextMenu.style.display = 'none';
    }
   else {
       e.preventDefault();
       rgtClickContextMenu.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
       rgtClickContextMenu.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
       rgtClickContextMenu.style.display = 'block';
     }
  });
```

This is where issue is happening:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
      console.log(e.target.className);
      console.log($('#tblJ1:hover, tbody:hover, tr:hover, td:hover').length );
      if (e.target != MyTarget) {
           rgtClickContextMenu.style.display = 'none';
      }....
```

Some CSS:

```
  <style>
    .cmenu { position:fixed; display:none; }
    .cmenu ul, #menu li {
        list-style:none;
        margin:0; padding:0;
        background:white;
    }
    .cmenu { border:solid 1px #CCC;}
    .cmenu li { border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; }
    .cmenu li:last-child { border:none; }
    .cmenu li a {
        display:block;
        padding:5px 10px; 
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#57889c;
    }
    .cmenu li a:hover {
        background:#57889c;
        color:#FFF;
    }
</style>
```

> If I keep menu hidden everything works but not when it is shown.

Comment: Try to provide a "full table" including tbody etc. also "tag-attribute" is not valid for td-elements

Comment: tag was meant to show what is happening here, I have updated exactly where issue I have found, menu when open causes issue because it is inside `topMost` div. Click  gets  captured by menu div,

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution,

check on click if any of your items is hovered currently:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  if($('#tbl:hover, tbody:hover, tr:hover, td:hover').length > 0){

    // on elements, not closing

  }else{

    // not on elements (close-condition)
  }
});
```

I guess this one is better as a "click" will always cascade down all Dom-elements that are actually clicked including all containing and wrapping
 els

Comment: gives length for tfoot, thead but not td. Let me check if I have missed to provide some information. I will update question with menu code

Comment: Please check my updated question. now my question is, how to find element near click except menu div because that when open causes issue.